# In Angular, Is there a way to load the markup around the router-outlet without waiting for guards to resolve on first load?

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-router, router, router-outlet

In our Angular 12 app, We have guards that run checks via API calls to the backend to ensure the user has all permissions to view the requested route. The way guards work out of the box uses an all-or-nothing approach with regards to showing markup on the UI for the first load (By first load I mean the route that is loaded first when visiting the app in the browser). Meaning, if we have additional HTML code in the main app.component.html, say something like:

```
<nav></nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

And if the requested route has asynchronous guards, we are stuck with a blank page until they are resolved since the `nav` or `footer` components are also not rendered on the UI.

What I am looking for is a way to only block the `router-outlet` from loading until the guards are resolved, and show the `nav` and `footer` throughout the process.

We have the following code in the index.html:

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

In our app.component.ts:

```
<nav></nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

And we have a couple of routes that have guards that make API calls to the backend which take time to resolve and show a blank page on the UI until they're resolved. Until the guards are resolved, the markup in the browser only shows:

```
<app-root></app-root> <!-- no markup loads except the root selector -->
```

Is there a way to show all markup except the router-outlet until the guards are resolved for that route, so we have the nav and footer show even before the guards are resolved? So while the guards are being resolved, show something like this:

```
<app-root>
<nav></nav> <!-- The nav is visible even before guards are resolved -->
<router-outlet>
<!-- Empty until guards are resolved -->
</router-outlet>
<footer></footer> <!-- The footer is visible even before guards are resolved -->
</app-root>
```

I looked at using `RouteReuseStrategy`, but that only is helpful for subsequent route loads. I'm looking specifically for the first page load.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by setting the `initialNavigation` to equal `enabledNonBlocking` in my `RouterModule` options like so:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabledNonBlocking',
      ...
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```